# How to save the life of my process?

Tags: matlab, remote-access, putty, remote-server

I have the following problem: I want to run a really cumbersome calculation on a server via Putty in Matlab. Now I do not want to keep my notebook the whole time connected to this server, which is why I am searching for a solution to this problem. I know that screen in general works but I am not sure whether this could help me here too. The problem is the following: Each time I start this Matlab program I have no longer control over the terminal, since the Matlab program is still running. Therefore I am always forced to abort the process, which is what I do not want to happen. Is there anything that could help me.

What I need this:
1.)Start Matlab Application on server
2.)Disconnect from Server 
3.)Connect to Server
4.)Have access to Matlab again

I would highly appreciate it, if somebody could give me a reference to some commands that might be helpful in this situation.

Comment: Yes, `screen` is a good idea, and does exactly what you describe.  What's the question?

Comment: I agree with Peter. I used `screen` many times, especially while running large pieces of code that takes several hours/days to run. It will make this pretty easy.

Comment: @Peter and how do you close this window when there is a process still running? without interrupting it?

Comment: Please read the manual: http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/screen.1.php.  Short answer: C-a d to detach from the running terminal, then later `screen -r` to reconnect.

Comment: @Lipschitz may I ask you not to upvote this answer? I want to test one thing…

Comment: what do you want to test?

Comment: @Lipschitz  think I need one more answer without upvotes to win a badge.

Comment: in order to undo my upvote you have to make an edit to it

Comment: @Lipschitz ok… I took advantaged from it and added a little bit more information, but it won't work if it is not accepted. Anyway, sorry for disturbing you with it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, ok, that will do.

Comment: @Werner Lets not put badges before site quality. Asking people not to upvote your answer makes the site less efficient for all other users. The badge will come eventually ;-)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin it's ok. I was just curious to know if one answer with zero votes accepted by myself would count. Seems it does not x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Peter said, `screen` is one good solution. A brief tutorial:

**Connect to server**

- `screen -S SectionName`
- `matlab -nosplash -nodesktop` or `-nodisplay` or `-nojvm` depending if you have allowed X11 forwarding on putty (you can check this by simply open a figure and check if you can see it with -nodesktop option)
- Ctrl+a d to detach
- Log out

**Reconnect to server**

- If you are using X11 forwarding, you may need to update your display on the screen, so: `echo $DISPLAY`, copy its result
- `screen -rd SectionName`
- If you are using X11 forward, update display on screen export DISPLAY="value echoed outside screen" (I think the opposite also works, you set the log display into the screen display)

**Finish Screen**

- Exit matlab and type `exit`

**List open screens**

- `screen -ls`

**Terminate unresponsive screen**

- Ctrl+a Ctrl+k and answer y

**Navigate through `screen` screen:**

- Ctrl+esc and then use arrows or: ctrl+u to go half screen up and ctrl+d to half screen down

**Exit broken connection screen**

- ~ .

Note: You can have more than one screen section running, or you can open multiple `screen` windows by using Ctrl+a Ctrl+c

Note2: `screen` command may be very addicting, use it with cautious. Don't forget to read its man page.